# access python ctypes structure from c shared library

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I wrote a python code to passing ctypes structure to c library function

python code:

```
from ctypes import *

class Info(Structure):
   _field_ = [("input",c_int),
              ("out",c_int)]

info = Info()

info.input = c_int(32)
info.out = c_int(121)

lib = CDLL("./sharedLib.so").getVal
a = lib(byref(info))
```

c code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct info{
    int input;
    int out;
};

void getVal(struct info *a){
    printf("in = %i \n", a->input);
    printf("out = %i \n", a->out);
}
```

compile it using command :
`gcc -shared -fPIC -o sharedLib.so sharedLib.c`

output :

```
in = 0 
out = 0
```

My problem is, why output is different from value that i set in python code. Is there any solution ?
Im in 32-bit environment

Answer (score 6):

In the ctypes structure definition, you wrote `_field_` instead of `_fields_`. As a result, the fields aren't translated to their C equivalents.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding:

```
lib.argtypes = [POINTER(Info)]
```

before calling lib.

Comment: +1 for the advice to set argtypes, typically good to also set restype.  If you set both of these Python does its best to protect the user from seg faults by doing a bit of checking.